# Can't able to sort list of numbers in listbox using insertion sort algorithm

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to apply insertion sort on list of numbers in listbox, I know, I can sort it with built-in sorted function but I'm trying to practice algorithms by writing their code but can't able to do
this.

It just swap index 1 with 2 but not sorting all the numbers in ascending order.

What's the problem with my code?

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsSort.Click
    'Dim selectedItems = lstBox2.SelectedItems.Cast(Of [String])().ToList()
    Dim arr = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of [String])().ToList()
    Dim j = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
    Dim Key As String

    For Each j In ListBox1.Items
        j = 2
        Key = ListBox1.Items(j)
        i = j - 1

    Next
    While (i > 0 And ListBox1.Items(i) > ListBox1.Items(j))
        ListBox1.Items(i + 1) = ListBox1.Items(i)
            i = i - 1

        ListBox1.Items(i + 1) = Key

    End While


End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in that first For loop?  You're using j as the loop variable but then setting it to 2.  Add `Option Strict On` to the top of your source file and you'll see why that loop won't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There you go buddy. Picture the numbers in my array as items in your listbox

```
Dim SortNumber() As Integer = {5, 6, 3, 1, 8, 9, 4, 2, 7, 0}
Dim yCount As Integer = 0
Do
    Dim CurNumber As Integer = SortNumber(yCount)   'Save current number
    Dim xCount As Integer = 0
    If yCount > 0 Then xCount = yCount - 1     ' start shift from here
    Dim ReplaceNum As Boolean = False
    Do While CurNumber < SortNumber(xCount)       'shift all position until current number is bigger then the one being shifted
        If CurNumber < SortNumber(xCount) Then
            ReplaceNum = True                'Number shifted save current number at the right position
            SortNumber(xCount + 1) = SortNumber(xCount)
        End If
        xCount -= 1
        If xCount = -1 Then Exit Do
    Loop
    If ReplaceNum = True Then SortNumber(xCount + 1) = CurNumber  'Place the current number at the right position
    yCount += 1
Loop Until yCount = SortNumber.Count
```